# Why does thick Hr show 2 lines which is ugly (CSS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

apply this style to make thick `HR` tag

```
.thickHr{
    border: none;
    height: 6px;
    /* Set the hr color */
    color: red; /* old IE */
    background-color: red; /* Modern Browsers */
}
```

Then here is the result in IE & Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, there is a tiny line run on top of the thick red line which is really ugly.

So how to remove that tiny line?

If that is the way How `Hr` renders, then can we have other style (not `Hr`) that do the same thing?

Note: i still prefers `hr` than other tyle.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me http://jsbin.com/qefaz/1/edit

Comment: in my Chrome it has 2 lines

Comment: What Chrome version, what OS? Windows I suppose...

Comment: so if it does not render the same look in different browser then can we have other style that do the same thing like Hr but ok in all browser?

Comment: i am using Chrome : Version 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: Why can't you simply use a `div`?

Comment: I am using Gwt so not sure how to style with div in Gwt

Comment: Using this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VS8VC/ - all ok in IE11, Chrome (33.0.1750.154 m), FireFox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use border-top or border-bottom

```
     .thickHr{
      border-top: 6px solid red ;
      color: red; /* old IE */
      background-color: red; /* Modern Browsers */
              }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZpAv/)

Comment: why it still very thick even i use border=top:1px?